# Ionic In-App Purchases

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, in-app-purchase, ionic3

Trying to implement in-app purchases to my ionic project. Not sure which one to go with, there are limited amount of resources for both.

I've found these tutorials:

In-App-Purchase: https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/

In-App-Purchase2:

1. https://medium.com/@andrew.thielcole/in-app-purchases-with-ionic-3-af13b21f49f2
2. https://github.com/thielCole/ionic-iap2

Is there one that is more preferred over the other? I'm using Ionic 3 and not sure where to start.

*EDIT*: Added second link for in-app-purchase2 per @franswa 's suggestion

Comment: I am using the first one and it works fine.I tested the second one last month and had some issues but now it should work fine. Take a loot at this repo for the second one: https://github.com/thielCole/ionic-iap2

Comment: Thank you I'll check it out - I'm reading that they're a good amount of crashes (mostly in the android) for the first in-app-purchase, what has been your experience? @franswa

Comment: I did quite a lot of testing and it worked fine, no crashing.

Comment: How do you test these? Seeing as Ionic Serve (and I believe ionic view) doesnt use cordova? How would you test the Apple and Android payment processes with ionic 3? @franswa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments I did a lot of testing with In-App-Purchase: https://alexdisler.com/2016/02/29/in-app-purchases-ionic-cordova/

Everything went fine. You have to deploy the app on the device for the testing:

```
ionic cordova run android --device
```

Then you have to create a product in the Google Play store and buy this test IAP from the app (using another account - not your developer account: the Google Account on the test device should not be the same as the developer account). The process is not so easy... but you can find good documentation online. Here's a useful link: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase/wiki/HOWTO#setup-android-applications

[UPDATE FROM NOV 2018]

- I now use the `cordova-plugin-purchase`: https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase
- It works really well and it is actively maintained.

Comment: Ok great, I got the device fired up - I'm (obviously) running into some errors. What's your best tactic to debug? Is there any way to bring up a console?

Comment: @cdh429 A simple vote up would have shown appreciation for answering your question. Acting 'cool' is not cool. Give the answer a vote up if he answered your question.

Comment: @franc Cooler than the other side of the pillow

Comment: I implemented In App Purchases 2 and I keep seeing this issue when I run my app: `TypeError: this.store.when(...).registered is not a function`. Similar type of errors occur for the other methods as well, such as: `TypeError: this.store.when(...).expired is not a function`. My codes are: `this.store.when(productId).expired((product: IAPProduct) => {
            alert('expired');
        });`. I am running my app in a browser, if that helps.